# After I have refreshed the page, the text inside the futurebuilder is not updating

Tags: flutter

**I am working with refreshing the data inside my page but after refreshing it is not updating unless I hot reload the application or restarting my app or log outing to the current user.**

I can see that the data has been successfully updated in cloud firestore and the updated address is already printed in my console.

```
      class _TabPage3State extends State<TabPage3> {
        String myEmail = '';
        String fname = '';
        String lname = '';
        String? myAddress = '';
        int Bdate = 0;

        final GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState> _refreshIndicatorKey =
            new GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();

        Future _fetch() async {
          final firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

          if (firebaseUser != null) {
            await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('users')
                .doc(firebaseUser.email)
                .get()
                .then((ds) {
              myEmail = ds.data()!['email'] ?? '';
              fname = ds.data()!['first name'] ?? '';
              lname = ds.data()!['last name'] ?? '';
              myAddress = ds.data()!['address'] ?? '';
              Bdate = ds.data()!['age'] ?? '';
              print(myAddress);
            }).catchError((e) {
              print(e);
            });
          }
        }

        @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          print('TabPage3 build');
          return Scaffold(
            body: RefreshIndicator(
              key: _refreshIndicatorKey,
              onRefresh: _fetch,
              child: SafeArea(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      //address
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
                        child: Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: bgColor,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                          ),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              Expanded(
                                child: Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: Column(
                                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                        children: [
                                          Text(
                                            'address'.toUpperCase(),
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              fontSize: 16,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          SizedBox(
                                            height: 5,
                                          ),
                                          //subtitle
                                          FutureBuilder(
                                            future: _fetch(),
                                            builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                              if (snapshot.connectionState !=
                                                  ConnectionState.done) {
                                                return Text('loading...');
                                              }

                                              return Text(
                                                '$myAddress',
                                                softWrap: false,
                                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                  color: grey,
                                                  fontSize: 14,
                                                ),
                                              );
                                            },
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              IconButton(
                                onPressed: () async {
                                  Navigator.push(context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                                    return updateAddress();
                                  }));
                                },
                                icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
onRefresh: () { return Future(() { setState(() { _fetch }); });},
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever using `Future.builder` try to use the snapshot data that you get from the future call. Also, try to use type annotations with `Future.builder`. Otherwise, you might end up with lots and lots of memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
setState(() { _myState = newValue; });
```

method to rebuild widget with new Values
read more about state in flutter dev [setState-method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html)